# Excel VBA FormatCondiitons for multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

I'm a novice in vba and I was confused on how to format a range based on multiple conditions. For example, I want to highlight the cells from columns(a:g) only if their value is less than 0 AND if the value in their respective row in column H contained the string "yes" or "no". The code I've written to perform this function doesn't work but looks like this.

```
Columns("A:G").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=AND(OR($H1 = ""YES"", $H1 = ""NO""),Columns(A,G) < 0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 120000
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @lebelinoz - This is essentially recorded code that actually **has** been cleaned up a touch. I've cut it down to the minimum below.

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
With Worksheets("sheet2").Columns("A:G")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
      Formula1:="=AND(OR($H1=""yes"", $H1=""no""), $G1<0, $A1<0)")
        .Interior.Color = 120000
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With
```

After rereading your original narrative, I believe that this may be a better formula.

```
Formula1:="=AND(OR($H1=""yes"", $H1=""no""), A1<0")
```

Comment: Was just about to post that fixed formula :). I got stuck on mistyping column H as G :0

Comment: Thanks for keeping an eye on me Scott! You just never know when I start adding the scotch to the coffee.

Comment: or perhaps the coffee to the scotch!